ASP.NET Core API - Calling Graph API returns immediate response to swagger
I'm building a ASP.NET Core web api and need to call Microsoft Graph API.
I got Microsoft Graph API to work but when i make a call like this:
var result = await graphClient.Users[guestUPN].GetAsync();

A 200 response is sent to swagger if no user is found.
I added a try catch but the 200 response is sent and the application continues to run.
swagger UI response
try
{
   var result = await graphClient.Users[guestUPN].GetAsync();
   return result;
}
catch (ApiException ex)
{
   return null;
}

Anyone seen this behavior before?
Thanks

Which version of the graph SDK are you using? When I try calling that endpoint using a non existent email address, I get a 500 error. I'm using Graph SDK version 5.40.0, are you receiving a 200 response code but null value for the response content?

Perhaps it's because you are catching the exception, and returning null? What happens if you remove the try/catch? Do you get a 500 error?

Sorry i figured out the problem. I forgot to add "await" to the call that i was making from the IActionResult method. The inner method cycle kipped running since it was a task but the IActionResult ended, and there for returned the 200 status code to swagger.
Important note: Don't forget to make methods async.
Thanks again.
